# Titanium Backup batch options

Tags: backup, titanium-backup

Does "**Backup all user apps**" also include app data too and does "**Backup all system data**" include backup of messages and contacts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TiBu's FAQ](http://www.titaniumtrack.com/kb/titanium-backup-kb/titanium-backup-user-guide.html#backup) says:

> Click “Backup all user apps” (if you want just your apps) or “Backup all user apps + system data” if you want everything backed up. This doesn’t seem to always backup SMS and contact history.

Unfortunately it doesn't explain all options in detail -- but from the above quote one can conclude:

- "Backup all system data" normally includes contacts, SMS, etc (but *might* miss some history -- not clear if the latter a) refers to an old version, as I never experienced that, or b) is device-specific)
- "Backup all user apps" must include the data, otherwise the term *if you want everything backed up* wouldn't make sense.

To make sure, just visit the above mentioned FAQ for a closer check, which might answer other questions (you didn't know you've had ;) on the way.